# Value of element created in JS required in Spring MVC controller

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc

I created an input tag inside the javascript, and I also provide the attribute `name` to it,

```
var tdTotalEmployees = row.insertCell(k++);
    tdTotalEmployees.innerHTML = rowData.totEmployees !== null ? '<a href="../emp_list_sm/employee_details?ym=' + rowData.yyyymm + '&s=' + false + '&h=' + true + '" style="color: #0e90d2; text-align:center"  target="_blank"><h4>' + rowData.totEmployees + '</h4></a><input type="hidden" name="migrationRef" value=' + rowData.migrationReference + '>' : ' ------ ';
```

Now as usual, I need this variable value in my controller, I used `@RequestParam("migrationRef")String migrationRef`
it didn't work,

I used SOUT on `request.getParameter("migrationRef")`, it displays null. means no value supplied from, but when I inspect the element, I clearly see the value of this element

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/employee_details")
    private ModelAndView getEmployeeList(HttpServletRequest request) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("migrate_salary_hr/pre_migration_emp_list");
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        Userdetail loginUser = (Userdetail) session.getAttribute("loginUser");
        System.out.println("migration ref no" +request.getParameter("migrationRef") );
        try {

            mav.addObject("yearMonth", request.getParameter("ym"));
            mav.addObject("status", request.getParameter("s"));
            mav.addObject("historyList", request.getParameter("h"));

            if (loginUser.getEmployee().getRegion().getRegionId() != null && loginUser.getEmployee().getCircle() != null) {
                mav.addObject("Region", loginUser.getEmployee().getRegion().getRegionId());
                mav.addObject("circle", loginUser.getEmployee().getCircle().getCircleId());
            } else {
                mav.addObject("Region", loginUser.getEmployee().getRegion().getRegionId());
            }
            mav.addObject("orderBy", OrderByMap.PREMIGRATIONEMPLIST_ORDERBY);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mav;

    }
```

kindly suggest me the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the hidden input `migrationRef` is not sent to the server when one click on the link. That's why you don't see it server side.

I can see two ways to solve this :

1. **Either** add the parameter `migrationRef` into the `href` attribute of your link, and remove the useless `<input type="hidden" ...`
2. **Or**, if you really don't want to see the parameter `migrationRef` in the URL, you have to POST it using a form. In this scenario, the `action` attribute of the form should be of the like `action="../emp_list_sm/employee_details?ym=...&s=...&h=..."`. Then in the Spring MVC controller you will have to use `@ModelAttribute` in place of `@RequestParam` on a Java Bean that has a `migrationRef` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I think workaround will be create **form** element and onclick of **anchor** trigger form submit. This will enable you to post all the information.

```
<form action="/{you-url}">
        <a id="go" href="#" target="_blank"/>click here</a>
        <input type="hidden" name= "ym" value = "+rowData.yyyymm+"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="s" value="false"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="h" value = "true"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="migrationRef" value=' + rowData.migrationReference + '/>
        <input type="submit"style="display:none"/>
        <script>
            document.querySelector("#go").onclick = function(){document.querySelector("input[type='submit']").click()};
        </script>
    </form>
```